# Generating a matrix with a given number of 1s in random places

Tags: matlab, matrix, graph-theory

I am trying to create a connectivity matrix for a graph with N nodes. The connectivity rules state that it should have 1000 randomly assigned one way connections (nodes cannot be connected to themselves).

What I want to do is to generate a matrix NxN with mostly zeroes and 1000 ones in random places, but not on the main diagonal.

I really don't have any ideas on how to achieve this. I thought about generating a matrix of random numbers between 0 and N/1000 and then making those above (N-1)/1000 to be one and the rest 0, but this isn't very precise (I may get more or less than 1000) and I don't know what to do about the diagonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this. Find the indices of non-diagonal elements. Choose some of those at random, and then populate those indices with ones:

```
nn = 10; % Size of matrix
nr = 20; % number of random connections
ident = eye(nn);       
nd_idx = find(~ident); % Indices of non-diag elements
con = randperm(numel(nd_idx), nr); % Pick random elements
m = zeros(nn);
m( nd_idx(con) ) = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks quite similar to carandraug's answer, but doesn't involve sorting so it's probably faster.I decided to go with this. Plus I didn't know that matrices in matlab can be indexed linearly. I'm still in a heavy learning mode when it comes to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a matrix with exactly 1000 randomly located true values, my suggestion is to create a random matrix, and use the lowest or highest 1000 elements. To remove the diagonal, use `eye()`. So, something like this

```
N = 5000;
nNodes = 1000;
a = rand (N);
a(eye (N)) = 2;
threshold = sort (a(:))(nNodes);
b = false (N);
b(a >= threshold) = true;
```

I think Matlab hasn't implemented indexing of variable outputs yet, that's still only available in Octave. If that's the case, you will need to use a temporary variable to hold the sorted array which can take some memory for large matrices.

```
threshold = sort (a(:));
threshold = threshold(nNodes);
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, but Justin's answer seems to be faster as it doesn't involve sorting.

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate random matrix **A**
2. Round items
3. Generate matrix of 1s with 0s on main diagonal **B** (you can create matrix of ones than substract matrix with 1s on main diagonal from it)
4. Multply A by B

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by round items?

Comment: `A=round(A)` Where A is matrix of numbers in range (0,1)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from random import randint

if len(sys.argv)!=3:
     sys.exit("usage is :"+sys.argv[0]+" matrix-size num-of-connections")

matrixSize       = int(sys.argv[1])
numOfConnections = int(sys.argv[2])
i = 0 

while (i < numOfConnections):
     a = randint(1, matrixSize)
     b = randint(1, matrixSize)
     if (a==b):
         continue
     i+=1
     print "connection from %d to %d"%(a,b)
```

Comment: I'm really looking for an answer in Matlab (hence the tag). I can rewrite this in matlab probably, but I'm guessing there is a shorter way to do it there.

Comment: right, sorry, anyways I replaced it with a shorted (and correct) version. I posted it before I noticed the matlab tag.